# How to make simple JS slider fully responsive?

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple Js slider, and need to make it responsive for mobiles. But when i apply max-width to #slider and #image it hides whole div element. For example default width should be 500pxl and 300pxl height. For wide screen. It should automatically resize depend on mobile and tablet screen width. Is it possible?
html:

```
<body onLoad="photoA()">
<div id="slider">
<img src="Images/img1.jpg" id="image" >
 <img onClick="photo(-1)" class="left" src="Images/arrow_left.png">  
 <img onClick="photo(1)" class="right" src="Images/arrow_right.png"> 
</div>
```

css:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    }
#slider {
    height:350px;
    max-width:500px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
#image {
    height:350px;
    width:500px;
    position:absolute;
    }

.left {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:10px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
.right {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    right:10px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
.right:hover ,  .left:hover {
    opacity:0.6; cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for positioning your main image absolutely? It will only make your life miserable.

If you make the following changes, you'll get the desired result:

```
    #slider {
        width: 100%;
        max-width:500px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 5px auto;
        position:relative;
        border-radius:4px;
      }
      #image {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
```

To make your slider look even better, I suggest that you also use:

```
  .left {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left:10px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  .right {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right:10px;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
```

Note: The div disappeared because you cannot set max-width to the parent when all its children are positioned absolutely With no widths and heights or max-widths and max-heights (They behave as if they had the values not set).

Comment: But images are not some size. I need to mak them some size and responsive.

Comment: I am not sure whether I get it right. Every image must have SOME size. If the images aren't the SAME size -- that's a different story if we're talking about keeping the slider the same width and height.

The easiest, but not a very elegant solution could be:
Make a placeholder image and use the styles I suggested. (it MUST have relative position)

And the other images can be then placed as absolute using e.g. top, right, bottom, left: 0;